# reset toggle when screen resizes (multiple styles)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a site that has its navigation expand when a button is clicked/toggled (#nav-icon); one click 'open' next click' closed' etc. `#main` contains the site content, `#mytopnav` is the navigation. It is 'pushed down' by by adding 
 `top-margin:85vh` and `height` when clicked.

js

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    // Animate Toggle button
    $('#nav-icon').click(function () {
        $(this).toggleClass('open');
        $('#main').toggleClass('openMargin');
        $('#myTopnav').toggleClass('openHeight');
    });
});
```

css

```
#nav-icon { position: absolute; ...
#nav-icon.open { top: 80vh; }

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) { 

.openHeight { height: 80vh; }
.openMargin { margin-top: 80vh; }

}
```

html

```
<button id="nav-icon" class="navbar-toggler" type="button" onclick="toggleNav()">
    <div id="icon-wrap">
        <span></span>
        <span></span>
        <span></span>
        <span></span>
    </div>
</button>
```

The issue I have is when the screen is resized, the menu remains open (and all he styles applied when the button was clicked remain on.

Basically I want it to be 'reset' when the screen is resized. Essentially the equivalent as if they clicked the button again before resizing the screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A working example would have helped understanding the problem and suggesting the code but what i undertand that you want to remove the `open`,`openMargin` and `openHeight` classes from `#nav-icon`,`#main` and `#myTopnav` if the window is resized and want the menu to reset to its default position before it was clicked.

You can use javascript to detect if the window was resized and remove the class from the `#nav-icon`,`#main` and `#myTopnav` elements by adding the below code before the `</body>` tag

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    $(window).resize(function (event) {
        $("#nav-icon").removeClass("open");
        $("#main").removeClass("openMargin");
        $("#myTopNav").removeClass("openHeight");
    });
});
```

if you like to limit the above functionality to a specific width only lets say you dont want the styles to be reset unless the resize window width reaches `780px` then you can wrap the inner code in the check

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    $(window).resize(function (event) {
        if ($(this).width()<=780) {
            ..///rest of the code
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add an event listener waiting for a resize event to trigger a function which will close the menu.

```
function closeOnResize( event ){
  // your logic here
}

window.addEventListener("resize", closeOnResize);
```